# Why does does removing a line effect the next one?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I'm attempting to return different days based on a given date, such as the first Monday of the week, the Friday of the week, as well as days in previous and following weeks so that I can figure out the start and end of my pay periods (for my two jobs, each are different) as well as the pay date for that period.

When I remove the `Logger.log("Prev Monday > " + addDays(pMonday, -7));`
the next line's value changes. What is removed line doing to mess up the following one?

I'm using this in Google App Scripts so I can pull data from a Google Calendar to a Google Sheet easily. It also means no extra libraries.

```
function test_monday(){
  var theDate = new Date();
  theDate.setDate(16);
  theDate.setMonth(5);
  theDate.setFullYear(2016);
  theDate.setHours(12,0,0,0)
  Logger.log(theDate);

  var pMonday = new Date();
  pMonday = getMonday( theDate ) ;
  Logger.log("pMonday: " + pMonday)

  Logger.log("Prev Monday > " + addDays(pMonday, -7));
  Logger.log("Following Friday > " + addDays(pMonday, 4));
}

function getMonday( date ) {
    var day = date.getDay() || 7;  
    if( day !== 1 ) 
        date.setHours(-24 * (day - 1)); 
    return date;
}

function addDays(d, n){
  var date = new Date();
  date = d;
  var offset = n;
  date.setHours(24 * ( offset ));
  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date = d;
```

This line right here completely undoes the work you did in the previous line. It says that `date` is the *exact same instance* as `d`. That means that whenever you modify `date` (`date.setHours(24 * offset)`) you're also modifying `d`. You might as well be writing `d.setHours(24 * offset)` because they mean the same thing.

If you want to create a new `Date` object equal to another one, just pass the original into the `Date` constructor. So you could rewrite your function as:

```
function addDays(d, n) {
  var date = new Date(d);
  date.setHours(24 * n);
  return date;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so when I pass a value to a function it is already being  declared and I was messing that up?

Comment: @ThatChrisGuy No. Whenever you pass in `pMonday`, you're modifying that value. It's still the same object instance as you passed in but the date that it represents has changed. You're adding `24 * offset` hours to it. If you do `console.log(pMonday)` before and after you call `addDays` you'll see what I mean.

Comment: you are not passing a value, you are passing a reference. not super consistent or clear but that's how javascript is :)